# IntelliJ- how to find method calls?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, find

I have just started using IntelliJ for the first time on a project that I've just started working on, and am still getting familiar witht the setup and how it works. Previously when working on Java projects, I have predominantly used Eclipse as my IDE.

In Eclipse, when working on a particular method, there was the functionality to right-click the method, and select the option 'Find All References', to list everywhere in the project that the method was called.

I have made a few changes to the definitions of a couple of methods (the changes have mainly been in their parameters) in the project in IntelliJ, and now want to 'Find All References' on the methods, so that I can ensure that they are called with the correct parameters. However, when I right-click on the method definitions, and select 'Find Usages' from the menu, I get a popup message displaying the following warning:

> Method '`abc()` of class `def`' implements method of interface `ghi`. Do you want to find the usages of the base method?

Regardless of whether I select 'Yes' or 'No', the search results only return one result- the source file & line that I clicked on in order to do the search.

My guess is that there's something I need to change in the settings somewhere to ensure that doing this returns all of the places where that particular method is used in the code? I checked with a colleague, and when they do exactly the same thing, they get a list of all of the places within the project where that method is called...

How can I resolve this, so that I can find all of the method calls for the one I have highlighted?

Comment: Do you perhaps have some part of the code selected?

Comment: So that message isn't a warning, but rather it's trying to clarify an ambiguity. It doesn't know whether you want to look for `Interface.foo()` (more general) or *only* `Concrete.foo()` (more specific). That's why it asks you.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the method is used in more than one place? When your colleague did the same thing, did he do it on the same branch and same method?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F7 on PCs? This will display the settings dialogue for "Find Usages". My guess is that your colleague and you have different "Find Usage" settings.

Comment: The part of the code that I have selected is the method that I am trying to find all references to- nothing else. I am looking for all uses of that method anywhere in the code. Yes, I am sure that the method is used in more than one place- in a couple of places, where I've wanted to change the parameter for a given method, I have actually copied the method, so that I have two identical ones there, and then changed the parameters if the second one- in the places where I've done this, the compiler gives me a message saying that the method "is never used".

Comment: If the methods I'm trying to find the references for were never used, then the compiler would give me this error message on these too.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything special to get it to find all usages, right-click->Find Usages is all there is to it (in your case it is a method from an interface so it is asking you that extra question). My only thought is maybe you don't have all your source files marked as sources? Maybe usages are in another module and you don't have the module marked as a dependency? Kind of long-shot suggestions but the only thing I can think of. BTW, in the future when you change the signature of a method use Refactor->Change Signature, IntelliJ will make short work of changing the signature for you

Comment: Try to invoke `Find Usages Settings...` and check the scope it is searching in. This might be set to something like `Current File` by mistake.

Answer (score 13):

I usually use `Ctrl-Alt-H` for Hierarchy and get a list of all callers even in tests.

Comment: Control + Opt + h for MAC.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+*click* on method declaration?

Comment: This kind of thing is best suited to leaving as a comment on the question. It's not an answer because you're only asking for clarification. You'll be able to leave comments once you reach 50 rep :)

Comment: I am working on a macbook, so yes- CTRL + click is what I'm doing to get the 'right click' menu to appear...

Answer (score 3):

By selecting the method name (double click on it) and pressing `alt+ctrl+shift+f7` keys, a window named `Fined Usages` will popup. There is a checkbox in this window, you can check: `Usages`, `Overriding methods`, `Search for text occurrences` or `Skip result tab with one usage`. Then you can set the **scope** on `All Places` and click on `Find`. So, a search window appears and all classes and methods that called this method are listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use "Find in path" option which lets you search for a raw string in any files in the project (although it's of course configurable). It is under `Ctrl-Shift-F`.